# Automate file splitting with FFMPEG

Tags: bash, ffmpeg, automation

We currently use Wowza web streaming for events and would like to take the recorded streams and split them up based on events within the stream.

My thought would be to upload a file with the times listed and then loop through those times using FFMPEG to split the file.

Answer (score 0):

Use the [segment muxer](https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-formats.html#segment_002c-stream_005fsegment_002c-ssegment):

```
ffmpeg -i input -c copy -f segment -segment_times 30,78,129 -reset_timestamps 1 output_%03d.mp4
```

Note that it will segment at keyframes so your times may not exactly correlate.